# Parent Category menus are not clickable , How to make them clickable?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, menu, submenu

I need to make all the menu links clickable. But my magento site parent menu(which are having sub categories in it!!) are not clickable. How could I make them clickable. They all having their links also. Bit I could not found from which css class it is being not clickable.

Please Help.

I'm beginner in magento.

Thanks

Comment: This may depend on your theme. In the default theme they are clickable.

Comment: Yeah , I got that. How can I control it from theme ?

Comment: Am I supposed to guess how your theme looks like or how it works?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I can click on every menu item.

Comment: Mouse over on first menu item and Click on "Zoek Op Kleur" menu , it will not redirect !! Thats my problem. Bcoz its having sub menu item. all the menu items that have sub items its behaving same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure but I think the problem comes from the `skin/frontend/tatooland/default/js/app.js` file.
There is this section

```
nav.find('li.level1 a.has-children').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var elem = $j(this).parent();

    // Check if sub-menu is open
    var isSubMenuActive = elem.hasClass('sub-menu-active') ? 1 : 0;

    // On smaller screens, allow multiple sibling sub-menus to show at once,
    // but this is a large touch device, avoid multiple sub-menus showing at once.
    if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (min-width:" + (bp.medium + 1) + "px)")) {
        elem
            .siblings('.sub-menu-active')
            .removeClass('sub-menu-active')
            .find('.sub-menu-active')
            .removeClass('sub-menu-active');
    }
    if (isSubMenuActive) {
        elem.removeClass('sub-menu-active');
    } else {
        elem.addClass('sub-menu-active');
    }
});
```

I think this only adds a class to the elements that have child menu items.
Try removing the `e.preventDefault();` at the top and see what happens.
I also think this is for the mobile version. So if you remove what I suggested your website may behave strange on a mobile device.

Comment: Ohhh man !! Its working fab.. !! Thanks a lot !! I did not found any bugs on mobile version. Hope it will not get in other issues. Fingers crossed.

Comment: hi @Marius, can you give solution for Magento2?