# Disable click in parent button (just one button)

Tags: menu

How can i disable one button of menu? I tried this code but this is disable all the button where is the problem?

In this address i change the code:

```
app/code/local/my-theme-name/navigation/block/navigation.php
```

In this file i remove this code:

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
```

and replace this code instead of above:

```
  if($level==0){
    $html[] = '<a href="#"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
    }else{
    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
}
```

but all the buttons be disable, i want just one of them be disable, how can i fix this code?

Comment: you need to disable one menu item(category) but that item(category) should be active is that it what you needed??

Comment: @dh47 i want one root category be disable because it has children.

Comment: I am not getting you the root category should not have any action??

Comment: @dh47 for example i define menu with these items: one-two-three-four, and item one have sub-menu and i want item one, not to be clickable.

Comment: [Check here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33917/parent-category-menus-are-not-clickable-how-to-make-them-clickable)  this may work

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: @dh47 also it's not thing that i want