# Remove hover from categories Magento 1.9 RWD

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, menu, rwd

How can I remove hover from categories menu in Magento 1.9 RWD? I want only clickable categories.I found solutions for previous versions modifying the menu.js but it's not working with the 1.9 RWD.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you want only category and not the slide menu with all subcategory? If yes, you need to go

/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtemplate/template/page/html/topmenu

You will see the function of the menu and you can just add your menu here and erase the original menu. It is very easy. If you need more info, how to do, let me know.

Comment: I want the same menu with all subcategory, but i want to replace the hover with onclick.

Comment: I'm not sur but I think is a JS function, because on scss file _header-nav.scss we do not see any function to activate the sub-menu. An answer have been done here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33917/parent-category-menus-are-not-clickable-how-to-make-them-clickable

Comment: I need it for the new magento 1.9 rwd theme, that is totally different from this.

Comment: It is a JQuery function as per answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css

Comment: Another option with css only: http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You can manage with custom script also.Please check bellow script.

**Note :** Please change class based on your structure.

First, remove hover effect using this script.

```
jQuery('.nav-container ul li.parent a').on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Now Manage click event for the open menu, on first click menu open and second click to redirect on the category page.

```
jQuery('.nav-container ul li.level0 a').click(function(e){
jQuery('.nav-container ul li.level0.parent a').not(this).removeClass('over');
jQuery(this).toggleClass('over');

if(jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').length > 0){
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('over')){
        jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').css('display','block');
    }else{
        jQuery(this).parent().children('ul').css('display','none');
        window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');    
    }

    e.preventDefault(); 
}

});
```